# How can I manipulate Code Access Policy using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, .net

I had a task today to add a new Code Group to my PC, using mscorcfg.msc.  Having recently learned how to use Powershell, I thought, how can I do the same thing using Powershell (everything looks like a nail when you have a new hammer).
Despite doing a number of different web searches, I haven't yet uncovered any means for getting Powershell to look at the Code Access Policy.
Can anyone suggest a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line way to add code groups is via [caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz.aspx).  Powershell can of course be used to invoke this as well as be used to [create XML files for import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh1y1b72.aspx) into CASPOL.